# Creating A Service Bus SAS Token and Consuming Relay in WinRT

Tags: wcf, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay, winrt-httpclient

I have a Service Bus Relay (WCF SOAP) I want to consume in my Windows Store App. I have written the code to create a token as well as the client which is below.

The problem is that I get an AuthorizationFailedFault returned with a faultstring "InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature." And I can't figure it out.

My Create Token method:

```
private static string CreateSasToken()
{
    TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970,1, 1);
    var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600);
    string stringToSign = webUtility.UrlEncode(ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri) + "\n" + expiry;

    string hashKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Secret).ToString();

    MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
    BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;

    var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(stringToSign,encoding);
    IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(hashKey,encoding);

    CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
    IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);

    string signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage);

    var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
        WebUtility.UrlEncode(ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri),
        WebUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, Issuer);

    return sasToken;
}
```

My Client class:

```
    public partial class ServiceClient
    {
        public async Task<string> GetDataUsingDataContract(string item, string sasToken)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ServiceBusAuthorization",sasToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction",".../GetDataUsingDataContract");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "xxxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net");

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,ServiceUri);

            var content =new StringContent(@"<s:Envelope
                xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                <s:Header></s:Header><s:Body>"+ item +@"</s:Body>
                </s:Envelope>",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/xml");
            request.Content = content;

            HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            HttpContent stream = wcfResponse.Content;

            var response = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var returnPacket = response.Result;

            return returnPacket;
        }
    }
```

I have been successful consuming the Relay using Http (via Fiddler) by copying an unexpired token created by Micorosft.ServiceBus in a console app.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution which involved both methods being wrong.

**CreateSasToken method:**

A minor change involved setting the hashKey variable as byte[] and not string. This line:
    `string hashKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Secret).ToString();`
Changed to this:
    `var hashKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Secret);`

This change meant that I needed to use a different method to set keyBuffer.
This line:
    `IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(hashKey,encoding);`
Change to this:
    `IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hashKey);`

So the new CreateSasToken method is:

```
    private static string GetSasToken()
    {
        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600);
        string stringToSign = WebUtility.UrlEncode(ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri) + "\n" + expiry;

        var hashKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Secret);

        MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider =
            MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha256);
        const BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
        var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(stringToSign,
            encoding);

        IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hashKey);
        CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
        IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);

        string signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage);

        var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
            WebUtility.UrlEncode(ServiceUri.AbsoluteUri),
            WebUtility.UrlEncode(signature),
            expiry, Issuer);

        return sasToken;
    }
```

**Service Client Class**

A couple of things to note here.

1. In order for the request to work, the SAS Token had to be added to the header as a parameter of a AuthenticationValueHeader object. So I added the following method to my helper class (ServiceBusHelper) which held the Key, KeyName and SasToken as properties and the CreateSasToken as a method.

   ```
   public static AuthenticationHeaderValue CreateBasicHeader()
   {
       return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", SasToken);
   }
   ```
2. The HttpRequestMessage Content property had to be created a special way. Taking the item parameter passed in, which was a serialized WCF DataContract type I needed to do a few things to make the SOAP envelope. Rather than go through them in detail here is the entire class (one method only). I will comment on the code to handle the response immediately following.

   ```
   public partial class SalesNotifyServiceClient
   {
       public async Task<string> GetDataUsingDataContract(string item)
       {
           string returnPacket = "";
           string element = "";
           try
           {
               HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ServiceBusAuthorization",
                   ServiceBusHelper.CreateBasicHeader().Parameter);
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction",
                   ".../GetDataUsingDataContract");
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host",
                   "xxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net");

               HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
                   ServiceBusHelper.ServiceUri);

               //Creating the request.Content
               var encodedItem = item.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");

               var strRequest =
                   @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                   <s:Header></s:Header><s:Body><GetDataUsingDataContract xmlns=
                   ""http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/servicemodel/relay""><item>" +
                   encodedItem + 
                   @"</item></GetDataUsingDataContract></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

               var content = new StringContent(strRequest,
                   System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

               request.Content = content;

               HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
               HttpContent stream = wcfResponse.Content;

               var response = await stream.ReadAsStringAsync();

               //Handling the response
               XDocument doc;
               using (StringReader s = new StringReader(response))
               {
                   doc = XDocument.Load(s);
               }

               if (doc.Root != null)
               {
                   element = doc.Root.Value;
               }

               returnPacket = element;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               var message = e.Message;
           }

           return returnPacket;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In order to get at the DataContract object I had to do a few things to the response string. As you can see at the `//Handling the response` comment above, using StringReader I loaded the returned SOAP envelope as a string into an XDocument and the root value was my serialized DataContract object. I then deserialized the returnPacket variable returned from the method had my response object.